# How to save a variable javascript?

Tags: javascript, imacros

So im running this script and i want to be able to save the variable **stopNumber** after the script is finished running so that the next time i run this script the saved variable **stopNumber** can be set to the variable **loops** so that i dont have to manually set it all the time.

```
var loops = Number(prompt("Starting csv line?"));
var stopNumber = loops + 15;

for (csvLine = loops ; csvLine <= stopNumber ; csvLine++) {

iimSet ("-var_CSVLINE", csvLine);
iimPlay("Testing.iim");

}
```

Comment: If you arae trying to save stopNumber value you can use another variable to store it.

Comment: Yes but it wont save after the script is finished running and i try to call upon that variable some other day when i use the script again.

Comment: store it as a cookie. Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
or you can store in localStorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the value in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem("stopNumber", stopNumber);
```

Retrieve it with

```
stopNumber = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("stopNumber"));
```

More info here
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

try to use localStorage.

Like:
localStorage.stopNumber = stopNumber;

you may call it as localStorage.stopNumber