# Storing and retrieving in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I want to store data in localStorage. I want to make it like a database.

Here is a sample. A user will create an electronic test; it will have a Title and Description. More than one question, each with more than one choice.

Another user can create another electronic test. How am I going to store it in localStorage?

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
KEY                | VALUES
----------------------------------------------------------
Tests              | ["Sample","Sample2","Sample3"]
----------------------------------------------------------
Description        | ["Sample","Sample2","Sample3"]
----------------------------------------------------------
Sample2            | ["question1","question2","question3"]
----------------------------------------------------------
question3          | ["Question","choice1","choice2","choice3"]
----------------------------------------------------------
question3_ifAnswer | ["","","yes","yes"]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I think there is a better way to store it.
By the way, the question is dynamically added, as well as the choices in each questions.

How do I store and retrieve it in a better way?

Comment: throw it all into one object, then store the object using JSON.

Comment: @mohamediras, I tried the sample in above. I have done storing it like that. But I am hoping there is a better way.

Comment: @dandavis, How do I throw it into one object? what do you mean of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does look difficult to manage as a bunch of arrays.

I would probably store it as a javascript object like this, then convert it to json and store the resulting json strong in localStorage.

I assume you understand the limitations of localStorage

```
var tests = [
    {
        title: "title 1",
        description: "Desc 1",
        questions: [
            {
                name: "question 1",
                type: "text"
            },
            {
                name: "question 2",
                type: "multiple choice",
                options: [
                    {
                        code: "A",
                        description: 'Choice A'
                    },
                    {
                        code: "B",
                        description: 'Choice B'
                    },
                    {
                        code: "C",
                        description: 'Choice C'
                    }
                ],
                answer: ""
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        title: "test 2",
        description: "Desc for test 2",
        questions: [],  //etc
        answer: ""
    }
];

var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(tests);
```

Obviously I can only guess at you intentions so you would need to adjust this to suit your needs

And when you retrieve it as a JSON string from localStorage, convert it back to an object/ array with

```
tests = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
```

Comment: How can I retrive it in localStroage, and How can I edit it? for example, I would like to change the choices in the questions?

Comment: You could retrieve the JSON from localStorage, parse it to a POJO, modify it as needed and then convert it back to JSON and store it back to [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Well you would work on the `test` objects in the `test` array just as per normal JS object, then when you want to save it to local storage, convert it to a JSON string and save it. See this answer for putting something in out of local storage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754366/how-to-save-a-variable-javascript/27754481#27754481

Comment: What I mean is, How to get the value? for example, I want to get the total number of questions in "test1" test?

Comment: `var test1 = tests[0];`

`var numquestions = test1.questions.length;`

Comment: By the way. what if a creates a test? How can I add it in the tests variable?

Comment: `tests` is just an array, so `var newtest={title: "", questions: [] //etc};`  `tests.push(newtest);` will add it to the end of the array